# How will I do a property drill down?

Tags: c#, reflection, class, properties

How will I know if an object instance is a property or a sub property of another object instance?

for example I have this class structure:

```
public class Car
{
      public Manufacturer Manufacturer {get;set;}
}

public class Manufacturer
{
      public List<Supplier> {get;set;}
}

public class Supplier
{
      string SupplierName {get;set;}
}
```

And I only have two instances, the Car and the SupplierName; Using PropertyInfo in Reflection, How can I Implement a method such as

```
bool IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(object ObjectInstance, object TargetObejectInstance)
```

used as

```
IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(SupplierNameInstance, CarInstance)
```

this method will return true if the CarInstance's Property Manufacturer has a Supplier that has a SupplierName SupplierNameInstance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what your looking for?  Sorry if its not the cleanest - you will probably want to add some null checks in there as well.

```
private bool IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(Object Owner, Object LookFor)
{

    if (Owner.Equals(LookFor))
    {
        // is it a property if they are the same?
        // may need a enum rather than bool
        return true;
    }

    PropertyInfo[] Properties = Owner.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in Properties)
    {
        var Value = pInfo.GetValue(Owner, null);

        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(Value.GetType()))
        {
            // Becomes more complicated if it can be a collection of collections
            foreach (Object O in (IEnumerable)Value)
            {
                if (IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(O, LookFor))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(Value, LookFor))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Edit: I just noticed that if `LookFor` is `IEnumerable` then you may end up with an issue, will leave that to you to sort out ;)

Comment: I think LookFor, in my case, will not be an IEnumerable. I'll try this logic if it will work, and I strongly think it will.

Comment: It worked, I just added a depth parameter to indicate how deep it will dig the sub properties because it seems to be a never ending loop without that. And ofcourse the null checks and some exception handling. Thanks very much.

Comment: it's a little bit lag for my application but I think, using the new Task Parallel library(TPL) of Microsoft will help.

Comment: Any tips on optimizing this method?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any optimization offhand - reflection is pretty slow in general. I wouldn't have thought you would have any infinite loops unless you have a looping property 'O1.Prop = O2; O2.Prop = O1;' you could probably pass a stack of objects which have already been compared and make sure that the 'Value' you just got hasn't occurred before.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to use reflection for the particular example you describe:

```
bool IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(Supplier supplierInstance, Car carInstance)
{
    return carInstance.Manufacturer.Suppliers.Contains(supplierInstance);
}
```

(By the way, you missed out the name of the `List<Supplier>` property in your `Manufacturer` class. I've assumed that it's actually called `Suppliers` in my code above.)

Comment: Yeah it's Suppliers. 

Assuming that the signature of the method is 
bool IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(object ObjectInstance, object TargetObejectInstance)

the method should not be specific to a Supplier and a Car. I want it to be generic in a way that you can pass any instance of any object. If I do 

IsPropertyOrSubPropertyOf(supplierInstance, ManufacturerInstance) 

it should still return true if the Supplier instance is a part of the manufacturer's property.